# Install Adblock Edge for Tor Browser

Tags: add-on

I read in the FAQ that the Tor project officially doesn't recommend further Firefox add-ons. But it so happens that I won't use the Tor browser unless I get Adblock Edge to work like in my regular browser.

So how can I install it? I am on Linux. I open the Add-ons, select Adblock Edge 2.1.9.1-signed, click 'install'. It downloads something then responds:

> There was an error downloading Adblock Edge.

What now?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the add-on itself. I can download and install other add-ons, but this one isn't playing ball. Perhaps a compatibility issue between the version of the add-on and the version of Firefox that Tor Browser is based on?

Comment: although **it is not recommended to change the TBB-profile**, i would suggest [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) instead of [Adblock Edge](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/adblock-edge/), because it was discontinued in favor of uBlock Origin!

Comment: It so happens that by installing Add-ons, you stand out more, making it easier to track you. Tor won't hide you if you don't use it properly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that only the built-in add-ons page of Firefox has this problem. If one installs via https://addons.mozilla.org/ it works.